# COMPLETE - pureJS issue with writing data, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, function, document, issue-tracking

I am trying to take the data from "create_name()" and write the outcome to the

```
<p id="name"> </p>
```

updating the variable name to show the new version.

however I am a bit lost in honesty and instead it returns "undefined" as the name.

the code obviously gets to this part and then fails:

```
Writedata(create_name); // now write our username
menu_function();
}


function Writedata(nameUser){
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML='hello ' + nameUser + ' below are your options'; // write the username.
}
```

You can see the code for the entire section I am trying to make work here.

I hope I explained clearly enough.

Any Questions? feel free to ask, all help is appreciated!

```
init(); // lets start the inital func

function init(){ // Do some asking shit
    var name = prompt('hello, what is your name?'); // ask for the name
    document.write('<p id="name">hello ' + name + ' </p>');
    document.write('<p id="user" >1 - create a username</p>');
    document.write('<p id ="play" >2 - Play Quiz<p>');
    document.write('<p id="reload">3 - quit and reload<p>');
    Writedata(name); // tell our witer to write the name
}

function menu_function() {
    var choice = prompt("hello " + name + " please select an option from the list to your left");

    switch (choice) {
        case "1": opt1_function(); break;
        case "2": opt2_function(); break;
        case "3": reload_method(); break;
        default: menu_function(); break;
    }
}

menu_function();

function opt1_function() {
    alert(name + " you have selected option 1");
    create_name();
}

function create_name() {
    var forename = prompt("what is your forename?");
    var surname = prompt("what is your surname?");
    var username = alert("hello " + forename + " " + surname);
    var string1 = forename.substring(0 , 1);
    var create_name = alert(string1 + surname);
    Writedata(create_name); // now write our username
    menu_function();
}

function Writedata(nameUser){
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML='hello ' + nameUser + ' below are your options'; // write the username.
}
```

Comment: `alert()` doesn't return anything, so what did you expect `create_name` to equal?

Comment: @Moob

I want the text within the alert to be the new value of the variable "name" to replace "name" in the:  

   'document.write('<p id="name">hello ' + name + ' </p>');'

through these lines:

    'Writedata(create_name); // now write our username
    menu_function();
    }

    function Writedata(nameUser){
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML='hello ' + nameUser + ' below are your options'; // write the username.
    }'

Got myself a bit lost.

Comment: Fixed it! Just removed the alert and now it says `var create_name = string1 + surname;
Writedata(create_name); // now write our username
menu_function();`  and it works!

Comment: See Alper's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop assigning alert() function return values to variables, alert() has no return value [look at this alert definition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)

change this line

```
var create_name = alert(string1 + surname);
```

to

```
alert(string1 + surname);
var create_name = string1 + surname;
```

Comment: cheers! works perfectly now! I knew it must of been me being a bit blind! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Changed the data within the create_name() function to this:

```
function create_name() {
var forename = prompt("what is your forename?");
var surname = prompt("what is your surname?");
var username = alert("hello " + forename + " " + surname);
var string1 = forename.substring(0 , 1);
var create_name = string1 + surname;
Writedata(create_name); // now write our username
menu_function();
}

function Writedata(nameUser){
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML='hello ' + nameUser + ' below are your options'; // write the username.
}
```

and now it works!